# VNC viewer displaying lock screen but shows a black screen after logging in

Tags: virtualbox, vnc

When I connect to a remote machine using any VNC Viewer, I am able to see the login/lock screen and even enter password to log in. But as soon as log in, I am getting a black screen. The keyboard and mouse events are passed successfully though.

I have tried using different VNC viewers and have tried connecting from different machines.

The remote vm is running over Oracle Virtualbox with Guest Additions installed.

There is no issue in connecting to Other vm's on the same virtualbox.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Disabling 3d rendering in the virtual-box configuration makes it work. Although I still don't know why. If anyone knows please enlighten us.